# How to add one image onto another in java

Tags: java, image

I have an image with a plain background. Now I need to place another image onto it at (x, y) location. How is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a `BufferedImage` with desired size. Use `getGraphics()` of the image and paint the first image and then the second one. `Graphics` has the method

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, 
                      Color bgcolor,
                      ImageObserver observer)
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) method. Maybe something like so:

```
try
{
    BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
    BufferedImage logo = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));

    Graphics g = source.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how to get the final result of this? I mean the result image?

Comment: @vigamage: If I recall, you could use a similar class to write the resulting image to a file.

Comment: You can use ImageIO.write(source,"JPG",targetFile) to write the resulting image to file